# I can't request array data

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

This is the buidForm

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('categorie', EntityType::class, [
        // This field shows all the categories
        'placeholder' => 'Choisissez une option',
        'class'    => Categorie::class,
        'mapped' => false,
        'multiple' => true
        ]);
}
```

And this the controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(RechercheCandidatType::class, null);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $categories = $request->request->get('recherche_candidat_categorie');
      foreach ($categories as $categorie) {
            dump($categorie);
        }
}

return $this->render("test.html.twig",['form' => $form->createView()]);
```

And this the TWIG

> ```
>         {{ form_start(form,{'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
>         <div class="">
>             {{ form_errors(form) }}
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="row">
>             <div class="col">
>                 {{ form_row(form.categorie) }}
>             </div>
>         </div>
>
>         {{ form_row(form._token) }}
>         <button class="btn btn-success">Afficher</button>
>         {{ form_end(form) }}
> ```

[image: ![enter image description here]
This is from Inspect element

```
 <form name="recherche_candidat" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="">

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group"><label class="required" for="recherche_candidat_categorie">Categorie</label><select id="recherche_candidat_categorie" name="recherche_candidat[categorie][]" required="required" class="form-control" multiple="multiple"><option value="1">Web</option><option value="2">Mobile</option></select></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" id="recherche_candidat__token" name="recherche_candidat[_token]" value="B25v0VqQWQbERl3c3_EsGkyiVZTvC8xn37szufreGmo" />
            <button class="btn btn-success">Afficher</button>
            </form>
```

The problem is after submitting, i can't receive the array data ($categories = **null** )

> PS : recherche_candidat_categorie = ID of select form

Comment: Can you show the rendered HTML code of the form ?

Comment: question updated

Comment: This is the Twig template, not the **rendered** html

Comment: you mean this ? return $this->render("test.html.twig",['form' => $form->createView()]);

Comment: I mean the HTML code you have from `<form ... >` to `</form>`

Comment: Question updated

Comment: I cant see anywhere where you are defining 'teams'. Instead of getting data from the request using `$request->request->get('recherche_candidat_categorie')` could you try `$form->getData()`

Comment: sorry not teams, its $categories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get data using id, you have to use the name, So instead of "recherche_candidat_categorie", use this

```
$request->request->get('recherche_candidat');
```